# How to insert a name automatically in the SQLite database when we type that name in the edit box?

Tags: android, sqlite

My actual meaning is that I want to make an app in which there will be a `textbox`in the UI and some names will be stored in the database and if I type the name's first word which is in the database  that name should appear automatically  like the `autocomplete` view but when we type a  new name which is not in the database  in the search box then it should add that new name automatically in the database

Comment: Normally you have them press a button, then add the name when the button is pressed.  Anything else and you have the partial word problem-  if someone is typing Sally, you don't want to accidentally add "Sall" to the database.  So you need some way to know she's done and wants this added.

Answer (score 0):

So what you are trying to do is (1) populate the SQLite database with names as the user enters them - but (2) you always want to retrieve names that are in the database and use these as suggestions for autocomplete.

for (1) here is a good and complete tutorial on [SQLite in Android](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm) - this should cover what you need to do (including updating/deleting). More specifically, you want to store what the user is entering in the Textbox - so something like this:

```
....
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
//supposing you declared the edit-text as (edtName) properly before...
String nameValue = edtName.getText().toString();
contentValues.put("name", name);
db.insert("<tablename>", null, contentValues);
```

For (2) - Autocomplete - I suggest you look at [this AutoComplete example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html#AutoComplete) as well as the [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) reference. Since you want to retrieve suggestions from SQLite, you should first retrieve the list names from the database and then instantiate your adapter - example (adapt to your use case):

```
    //supposing you have a helper method "getNames" which executes select * query
    //and returning list of all names...
    String[] namesFromDB = yourDBHelper.getNames();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, namesFromDB);
    AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.names_list);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I hope this gets you started.

Comment: In the first part where you are showing how to insert name in the database  but there is a condition I want to insert that names only which are not there in the database.

Comment: But since you are doing AutoComplete, if the name already exists, it will be suggested to the user - so you do not need the condition before inserting. You can accept the answer if it helps...

Comment: I mean to say that when I type a new name which is not in the database that name should should only be inserted in the database but when aoutocompletes complete the name which is in the database  that names will also be inserted again in the database

Comment: I still don't understand why you will need to check if the name exists or not because you will insert it anyway (according to you last comment, which does not make sense) - unless I am missing something - but the suggested answer should cover your use case in terms of getting suggestions from the database.